# Handsontable Column Selection and Sorting Issue

Tags: jquery, css, html, sapui5, handsontable

I am using Handsontable in my SAPUI5 application. I am unable to give a scroll to the Handsontable Grid, where the Column Headers remained fixed. Due to which when the user clicks on the column header for the sorting the column, the entire column gets selected and the scroll runs to the last row in the table. Also the sorting does not get restricted to the second column alone in-spite of specifying it in the settings.

Following is my code followed by the screenshot. Please help me fix the issue.

**View:**

```
<HTML xmlns="sap.ui.core" busy="false" busyIndicatorDelay="1000" visible="true"
content="&lt;div id='batchesSheet' class='hot handsontable' style='width: 90%; overflow: hidden'&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
preferDOM="true" sanitizeContent="false" afterRendering="BatchesHOT">
</HTML>
```

**Controller:**

```
hotBatches = new Handsontable(container, {
   data: batchesData,
   rowHeaders: true,
   columns: [{data: "User", readOnly: true}, {data: "Timestamp", readOnly: true}, {data: "Status", readOnly: true}, {
      data: "Remarks",
      readOnly: true
   }],
   colHeaders: ["USER", "BATCH SUBMISSION TIME", "STATUS", "REMARKS"],
   colWidths: [100, 220, 180, 350],
   columnSorting: {
      column: 2,
      sortOrder: true
   },
   sortIndicator: true,
   contextMenu: true,
   search: true,
   outsideClickDeselects: false,
   cells: function (row, col, prop) {
      var cellProperties = {};

      if (col === 2) {
         cellProperties.renderer = "statusRenderer";
      }
      else {
         cellProperties.renderer = "textRenderer";
      }
      return cellProperties;
   }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what's the issue? Is it that you want the headers to stay frozen? Or that your table scrolls all the way to the bottom when you sort? Or both? The first issue is with your `overflow:hidden` option

Comment: Both @ZekeDroid. Both are the issues!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so to fix those two issues you would do the following:

To have your headers stay frozen, you add the following to your initialization of the table:

```
fixedRowsTop: 0
```

To get the scrolling working better, add `overflow:auto` instead of `overflow:hidden` like you have it right now on your HTML object. The scrolling all the way to the bottom is a bug which I'm not sure what's causing it, but to make it scroll to the top, just put a call at the end of your update method which calls

```
$("#batchesSheet")[0].scrollTop = 0; // sets scroll all the way to the top
```

Hope that helps!